# importing SSL certificate into SIM800C

Tags: ssl, gsm, at-command, sim800

I want to upload SSL certificate in SIM800c modem using At Command and following the same process as mention in the document. But I am getting failed every time.
The process as below for AT Command:

```
AT+FSCREATE=C:\IOTHUB.crt<CR><LF>

OK<CR><LF>

AT+FSWRITE=C:\IOTHUB.crt,0,1188,10<CR><LF>

>
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

OK<CR><LF>


AT+SSLSETCERT=IOTHUB.crt,"ABC123"<CR><LF>

OK<CR><LF>

+SSLSETCERT: 1<CR><LF>
```

Any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

From [David Betancourt](http://www.embeddedadvice.com/u/david_betancourt/summary)'s [comment](http://www.embeddedadvice.com/t/security-over-mqtt-using-encryption/86/30): use QCom software from Quectel to upload `.crt` file.

Download: [link](https://dl.sisoog.com/Quectel/Sisoog.com_QCOM_V1.6.zip) or [link](https://downloads.rakwireless.com/Cellular/WisLink-Cellular-RAK2011/Tools/QCOM_V1.6.zip)

Steps:

- launch QCom
- select your desired `.pem` or `.crt` file. It's size will be displayed in the middle text box, use this size in following at commands.
- now use at commands to get to the point that modules asks for certificate string, now use "send file".

for example:

```sh
# Notice: lines with ":::" are results.

# delete the file (if it exists)
AT+FSDEL=C:\User\my.cer
::: OK
# or if not exist
::: ERROR

# create an empty file
AT+FSCREATE=C:\User\my.cer
::: OK

# open created file to write. you must set "size" properly according to your .crt file. In my case it has 1376 bytes.
###### AT+FSWRITE=<path>,<mode>,<size>,<timeout> ####
AT+FSWRITE=C:\User\my.cer,0,1376,30
::: >
   `at this point click on the "send file" button`
::: OK

# to view the file
AT+FSREAD=C:\User\my.cer,0,1376,0
::: content of the file ....

# set certificate
AT+SSLSETCERT="C:\User\my.cer"
::: +SSLSETCERT: 0
```

Is HTTPS working after these steps? The answer was NO for me.
I imported successfully but I still could not get https connection to some websites.